# Get value of a column and store it into an array - DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have the following code:

```
int countRows = dataGridView3.SelectedRows.Count;
              int rowIndex = 0;

              foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView3.SelectedRows)
              {

                  int selectedRowIndex = dataGridView3.SelectedCells[rowIndex].RowIndex;

                  DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView3.Rows[selectedRowIndex];

                  capacity = Convert.ToInt32(selectedRow.Cells["Cust_Number"].Value);
                  capStore.Add(capacity);

                  rowIndex++;

              }
```

I try to go through each selected row in my DataGridView and store the value from the column "Cust_Number" into an ArrayList, so that I can change it later. Somehow he just grabs the second row each time I iterate and I have the same value in my ArrayList duplicated. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following code :

```
if(dataGridView3.SelectedRows != null && dataGridView3.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in dataGridView3.SelectedRows)
    {
        int tempVal = 0;
        if(dgvr.Cells["Cust_Number"].Value != null && int.TryParse(dgvr.Cells["Cust_Number"].Value.ToString(), out tempVal))
        {
            capStore.Add(tempVal);
        }
    }
}
```

This is simpler and safer.